# "princess of all things shoes" what does this phrase mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I read this in a blog as a profile description for a girl. The phrase is "princess of all things shoes" What does this mean?

Comment: 'All things linguistic / clothing / book ...' is a snowclone, snappier than 'everything connected with / involved in'.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *all things + noun* is an informal way of saying "everything about or pertaining to [noun]." Thus a Youtube channel about [all things Barbie](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQEJ0pRVvA4-yt3-1J-OYKg), the fashion doll by Mattel, or a restaurant in Wichita KS named [All Things Barbecue](https://m.facebook.com/allthingsbbq/?__tn__=C-R).

A variation labels a person a *lover of all things [noun]*, or to express special expertise, fame, or great enthusiasm for something, *the [noun of high rank/status] of all things [noun]*. So a female academic becomes [the doyenne of all things Byron,](http://www.teebylo.net/at-home-with-the-doyenne-of-all-things-byron....html) famous designer Diana Vreeland is the [grande dame of all things fashion](https://books.google.de/books?id=n0MyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22of%20all%20things%20fashion%22&source=bl&ots=r7XvSG_Kkv&sig=7PgI5dl-PwKYNwlbYcbSgqoKU8Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigsZ_679TYAhUFhqYKHcI0BCM4ChDoATAGegQICRAB), or a particular gelateria in Lucca, Italy, rather than a person, can be proclaimed [the king of all gelato.](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187898-d10258461-r507872500-Gelateria_Paniko-Lucca_Province_of_Lucca_Tuscany.html)

So the woman described as the *the princess of all things shoes* really knows shoes, loves shoes, and loves to shop for them.

Answer (score 0):

It means she's the leader, the fashion guru, on the shoe front. An enthusiast about everything to do with shoes. Probably has a vast shoe collection as well.