# Grammatical correctness of "With all things vampire"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I came across this sentence:

"That was the year the Twilight movie was going to come out, and the kids were agog with all things vampire."
— Shelley Dorrill (From Merriam-Webster's definition of [1.Agog](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agog))

I did quick search and this quote apparently comes from an [interview](https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CA325699140&sid=googleScholar&v=2.1&it=r&linkaccess=abs&issn=10949046&p=AONE&sw=w&userGroupName=anon%7E688e5fe8) with the author Shelley Dorrill.

Since vampire is a noun this sentence struck me as incorrect. I would have expected "the kids were agog with all things vampire-like/vampire-related" or, more so, "the kids were agog with all vampire-like/vampire-related things".

Was the interview setting that allowed for a laxer interaction (but then, why did MW dictionary choose to put this as a paradigmatic sentence?) or is it indeed grammatically correct?

Comment: Why do you dislike it? Would you accept "with all vampire things"?

Comment: @StuartF it sounds weird to me the ([noun] + "things") or the ("things" + [noun]) constructions. I would expect an adjective instead of a noun in this case.

Comment: Closely related, though they take the grammaticalness as a given:  [What does "All things X" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/what-does-all-things-x-mean); ["princess of all things shoes" what does this phrase mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426178/princess-of-all-things-shoes-what-does-this-phrase-mean)

Comment: It's using "vampire" as an abbreviation for "related to vampires"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 'all things vampire.' If there was a doubt there, I suggest it would be using 'agog with' rather than 'agog at…'